# How to use a value from one stored procedure in another?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, return-value, parameters

I have the following statement in a stored procedure:

```
DECLARE @Count INT
EXEC @Count = GetItemCount 123
SELECT @Count
```

Which calls another stored procedure with the following statement inside:

```
SELECT COUNT(Item) 
FROM tblItem 
WHERE ID = @ID
```

However when I test the call the `EXEC` outputs the value correctly but it
is not assigned to the `@Count` parameter correctly.

I've seen examples or stored procedures used like this, including here but none had a parameter and a return value used (that I could find).

The `ID` parameter is passed into the second statement which returns a count value used by the first stored procedure - all the info I have read seems to indicate this should work - but it doesn't the @Count value is always zero, even when the `GetItemCount` returns always the correct value.

This is in Microsoft SQL Server 2008 if that helps.

Comment: I was able to get this to work - having an output as a parameter was the solution - keep forgetting SQL is not like the programming style I'm used to.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

In your stored procedure, are you either

a) Assigning the value of the count to an output parameter:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetItemCount
  @id INT,
  @count INT OUTPUT
AS
  SELECT @count = COUNT(Item) FROM tblItem WHERE ID = @id
```

called as:

```
DECLARE @count INT
EXEC GetItemCount 123, @count OUTPUT
```

or, b) Assigning the count value as the return value:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetItemCount
  @id INT
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @count INT
  SELECT @count = COUNT(Item) FROM tblItem WHERE ID = @id

  RETURN @count
END
```

called as:

```
DECLARE @count INT
EXEC @count = GetItemCount 123
```

Comment: Thanks for this - it worked - did not think that an output would be a parameter - that's why I could not figure it out I was treating the display output as an output when in fact nothing was being returned - hence why it was zero when I read the value.

Comment: Have searched for this issue a few times since I asked this question and came back here and found the solution, wish could up vote each time it's helped me!

Answer (score 10):

Another way

```
DECLARE @Count table(counting INT)
Insert into @Count
EXEC GetItemCount 123 
SELECT Counting FROM @Count
```

Comment: @MortezaFarhadi It will work in 2008 as well. Did you get any error?

Answer (score 3):

The following will not work if there are no input parameters for the executed SP:

```
EXEC [dbo].insertproduc 'TEST', @ProductID OUTPUT --works
EXEC [dbo].insertproduc, @ProductID OUTPUT -- generates a parameter supplied when not needed error message if the insertproduc does not require parameters.
```

Best to use the following format for all cases (it works on all versions):

```
DECLARE @MyOutputVariable int 
EXEC @MyOutputVariable  = [dbo].MyStoredProc
```

Answer (score 2):

You should pass `@Count` as an output parameter.

```
Create Proc dbo.usp_Proc1

@Id int,
@Count int output

as begin

select @Count = Count(Item) from tblItem where id=@Id

end
Go

Declare @Count int
Declare @Id int

Set @Id = 1

Exec dbo.usp_Proc1 @Id, @Count output

select @Count
```

Comment: This example was also helpful, to getting my query to work correctly so thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The solution (b) given by Mr. Matthew will not work when u call this in an another stored procedure (Ofcourse solution (a) works perfectly when we use OUTPUT param). 
Alternation for the solution (b) is Mr.Madhivanan's solution. i.e, create a temp table and use it then drop it.

Below are other solutions..

We cannot get the value from an internal OUTPUT clause in a stored procedure directly.
So we have to use OUTPUT parameter or RETURN VALUE instead.

Please refer to the following suggestions:

**SOLUTION 1:**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertProduct] 
      @pName varchar(50) 
AS 


BEGIN 
DECLARE @MyTableVar Table(ProductID 
int) 


      INSERT Products 
      ( 
           pName 
      ) 
      OUTPUT Inserted.ProductID 
INTO @MyTableVar 
      VALUES 
      ( 
        @pName 
      ) 
RETURN (SELECT ProductID
FROM @MyTableVar) 
END 


DECLARE @ProductID int 
EXEC @ProductID = [dbo].insertproduc 'TEST' 
SELECT @ProductID
```

**SOLUTION:2**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertProduct]
      @pName varchar(50) , @pID int output
AS

BEGIN 
DECLARE @MyTableVar Table(ProductID int)

      INSERT Products 
      (
           pName 
      )
      OUTPUT Inserted.ProductID INTO @MyTableVar
      VALUES 
      (
        @pName
      )
SELECT @pID=ProductID FROM @MyTableVar
END

DECLARE @ProductID int
EXEC [dbo].insertproduc 'TEST', @ProductID OUTPUT
SELECT @ProductID
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are catching in the variable `@Count` is the status of execution of the stored procedure `GetItemCount`  and not the value as you are expecting. To capture that value, you have two ways.

1. To declare another parameter `@count` as `OUTPUT` in `GetItemCount`. So you will have `GetItemCount` declaration as follows:

   ```
    CREATE PROCEDURE GetItemCount @ID int, @count int OUTPUT
   ```

   Inside, you can use

   ```
    SELECT @count = COUNT(Item) 
    FROM tblItem 
    WHERE ID = @ID
   ```
2. To declare a table before calling the procedure and getting that value as a column.

Answer (score 0):

Simplifying it after reading all answers. Used two input and two output parameters.

Make sure you assign some values to output params in your stored procedure.

My stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyStoredProcedure]
    (@InParam1  VARCHAR(20) = NULL,
     @InParam2  VARCHAR(20) = '',
     @OutParam1 VARCHAR(20) = NULL OUT,
     @OutParam2 VARCHAR(20) = NULL OUT)
AS
BEGIN
    SET @OutParam1 = 'Whatever you want to return'
    SET @OutParam2 = 'Whatever you want to return'
    RETURN 0; --This is final value any SP returns by default 0
END
```

Call this stored procedure - I used two output params so we need to declare them before executing the stored procedure:

```
DECLARE @OutParam1 VARCHAR(20)
DECLARE @OutParam2 VARCHAR(20)
```

Use any variable (ex. @Var) even if you do not finally need from the stored procedure, but this will set your output params without any return data like it does return:

**Method 1:**

```
DECLARE @Var INT
EXEC @Var = MyStoredProcedure 'InParam1', 'InParam2', @OutParam1 OUT, @OutParam2 OUT
```

If you want to return some select statement from your stored procedure, and want to use these values, you can either hold them ia temp table or simply uses as a select query.

**Method 2:**

Insert into a temp table

```
@DECLARE @TableTemp TABLE
                    (
                        Column1 VARCHAR(20),
                        Column2 VARCHAR(20)
                    )

INSERT INTO @TableTemp
    EXEC MyStoredProcedure 'InParam1', 'InParam2', @returnParam1 OUT, @returnParam2 OUT
```

This will set the two output params from `MyStoredProcedure` and also insert the values that you pass from `MyStoredProcedure` as a select statement.

**Method 3:**

To simply use the returned values as a table data we can use this:

```
EXEC MyStoredProcedure 'InParam1', 'Inparam2', @returnParam1 OUT, @returnParam2 OUT
```

Output params are always set in all above cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this based on this answer by [Madhivanan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2996535/13307252):

```
DECLARE @tblItem table(Item INT)
DECLARE @Count INT

Insert into @tblItem 
EXEC GetItemCount 123 
SELECT @Count = Item FROM @tblItem
```